# how can I add title google maps but for marker

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

how can I add title google maps but for marker 
***important : marker   will vary by user***

```
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: map.getCenter(),
        draggable: true,
        map: map,
        title: ????            

        });
```

Comment: Unclear what you want. The title should vary by user, but how is it entered?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myCenter,
    label: 'Your Shop Name',
    animation: google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE
});
```